# Groups and Members database: Which of these two options is a good design?

Tags: database-design

Each group can have either 1 or 2 members, no more, no less. Every select of group data will need to retrieve the member data. The eventual state of each group will tend towards 2 members (full group).

```
Group
group_id | ...

Member
group_id | user_id
```

vs

```
Group
group_id | user_id_1 | user_id_2 | ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The first one is probably the best option.

Members of a group is a kind of data that could increase some day and if you keep the first option you will only need to add a new row in the Members table.
Also you can remove or add users from a group without messing with any possible Groups indexes and without needing to update which is a more expensive action.

Comment: Assuming your use case never comes to pass (use case is fundamentally tied to maximum of 2 users), is the first option still a good choice considering the extra memory overhead for storing the reference columns (5 columns vs 3 columns)?